# Android; A progressbar with a custom dialog

Tags: android, layout, dialog, progress-bar, splash-screen

I've have a custom dialog displaying a splash screen;

```
mSplashDialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this,R.layout.splash);
mSplashDialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
mSplashDialog.setCancelable(true);
mSplashDialog.show();
```

The splash layout has a ProgressBar on it;

```
LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/picture_splash"
ProgressBar
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:id="@+id/progressbar_Horizontal"
android:max="100"
LinearLayout
```

But when I try to reference to the progress bar;

```
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
        progress.setMax(100);
```

I've found out in the debugger that the app crashes on the second line because the object progress = null, empty zipp, nuttin :(

It seems like that the progressbar, once docked in a dialog is not accessable... :(

Somebody knows a way around this?

A ProgresDialog is not a option, because you can't customize it...

Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried inflating the layout first, then looking for the progress bar and then calling Dialog.setContentView(View)?

Comment: I'm still quite new to android dev, could you be a little more specific? thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are invoking findViewById() in the correct context. For example, what you currently have is equivalent to:

```
progress = (ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
```

If mSplashDialog is not part of the view hierarchy for "this", then findViewById will never find your progressBar. Perhaps you want something like:

```
progress = (ProgressBar)mSplashDialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats it! f*ck! This gives me a great inside on how to adress stuff in the future! glorifiedHacker for president! :D